# Fixing git-svn "File or directory is out of date; try updating"

Tags: svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm using git svn to be able to keep on working with Git locally, but push changes to an SVN server remotely.

I did a `git svn fetch` before doing `git svn dcommit`.

However, now the latter command gives back

`Merge conflict during commit: File or directory 'src/path/to/Images' is out of date; try updating: resource out of date; try updating at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 939`

I'm working in the Terminal application.

Any ideas about what I could do? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
git svn rebase
```

instead of

```
git svn fetch
```

to prepare your code for submission to SVN.  Subversion can only accept new commits, so git-svn must arrange your changes such that they are a sequence of new changes to SVN, and you need to rebase for that.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I eventually did. The part that scared me is that sometimes rebasing takes a whole lot of time, and can seem very illogical, like you're making a mistake while doing it. But there's no other way around it. You just have to continue rebasing until terminal tells you it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if one has two remotes, say `upstream` and `origin`, it appears that the diff occurs against the remote the branch is tracking.

```
git push <tracking remote> <branch>
git svn dcommit
```

worked for me.

I assumed that it would diff against my `upstream`, but it doesn't. It diffs against `origin`, since that's the remote the branch is tracking by default.